# HAProxy: Defer TCP connection to backend only after first data arrives

Tags: haproxy, tcp

I'm trying to understand if haproxy 2.2 or greater has a specific configuration that allows to defer opening the tcp connection to backend servers only after the first data segment is transmitted from the client.

I am running haproxy to balance long-lived tcp connections on a custom protocol where the client always speaks first.

However there are several incoming connections which do not send anything and just sit idle until they are timed-out by the backend nodes.

I'd like to avoid having haproxy opening the tcp connection immediately to the backend until the client has sent at least 1 byte.

I've tried to add the `defer-accept` option to the `bind` statements inside `frontend` sections but these seem not to have any effect.

My haproxy instance (v.2.2.20) is running on a Debian 10 VM with kernel 4.19.0.

Is there any other configuration option I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Was looking for this myself, found the answer in the the examples of the config reference: [https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#4-tcp-request%20content](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#4-tcp-request%20content:%7E:text=%23%20Forward%20HTTPS%20connection%20only%20if%20client%20speaks)

in the frontend:

```
tcp-request inspect-delay <whatever makes sense for your protocol>
tcp-request content accept if REQ_CONTENT
tcp-request content reject
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle that's exactly what I was looking for. I've just switched to a slightly different acl since every handshake on a new incoming connection is currently initiated on client side with two fixed header bytes, so I declared:

`acl valid_hs_start req.payload(0,2) -m bin 0103` then
`tcp-request inspect-delay 20s`, 
`tcp-request content accept if valid_hs_start`
and finally used `tcp-request content silent-drop`.

It looks like it's working nicely, I'll make further tests in a canary environment.

Comment: Note that if you don't specify unit for the delay and simply write e.g. `20`, the timeout will be 20 milliseconds.